# Jquery data picker not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Im fairly new to this so please bear with...
I'm using the tutorial @ http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/index.html
to allow the user to select dates from a calendar

however I can't seem to get it working could someone please advise if I am going about this the wrong way...

'jquery.datePicker.js & datePicker.css' can be downloaded at near the top of the page on...
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/index.html

1. Copy the code in the '•jquery.datePicker.js ' inside my  tags in my view
2. Copy the datePicker.css code into my css file
3. Paste the following into the top of my view page:

   ```
   <!-- jQuery -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!-- required plugins -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date.js"></script>
   <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.bgiframe.js"></script><![endif]-->

   <!-- jquery.datePicker.js -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.datePicker.js"></script>
   ```

This does not work...iv tried doing the first demo and replacting the .js data inside my`<script>` tags with

```
 $(function()
    {
        $('.date-pick').datePicker();
    });

and then adding the following to .css

    /* located in demo.css and creates a little calendar icon
     * instead of a text link for "Choose date"
     */
    a.dp-choose-date {
        float: left;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 5px 3px 0;
        display: block;
        text-indent: -2000px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: url(calendar.png) no-repeat; 
    }
    a.dp-choose-date.dp-disabled {
        background-position: 0 -20px;
        cursor: default;
    }
    /* makes the input field shorter once the date picker code
     * has run (to allow space for the calendar icon
     */
    input.dp-applied {
        width: 140px;
        float: left;
    }
```

could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Resources to add

> http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/date.js
>   http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js
>   http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/styles/datePicker.css
>   http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/styles/demo.css

```
<form name="chooseDateForm" id="chooseDateForm" action="#">
<fieldset>
<legend>Test date picker form</legend>
<ol>
<li>
<label for="date1">Date 1:</label>
<input name="date1" id="date1" class="date-pick" /></li>
<li>
<label for="date2">Date 2:</label>
<input name="date2" id="date2" class="date-pick" />
</li>
<li>
<label for="test-select">Test select:</label>
<select name="test-select" id="test-select" style="width: 170px">
<option value="1">Test SELECT </option>
<option value="2">Doesn't shine through</option>
<option value="3">Even in IE</option>
<option value="4">Yay!</option>
</select>
</li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
</form> ​
```

Javascript

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker();
```

CSS

```
 a.dp-choose-date {
     float: left;
     width: 16px;
     height: 16px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 5px 3px 0;
     display: block;
     text-indent: -2000px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: url(http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/images/calendar.png)
 no-repeat;  }4 a.dp-choose-date.dp-disabled {
     background-position: 0 -20px;
     cursor: default; } /* makes the input field shorter once the date picker code  * has run (to allow space for the calendar icon  */
 input.dp-applied {
     width: 140px;
     float: left; }​
```

Check the fiddler i have setup the demo there also remember to check the resources i have added

> http://jsfiddle.net/imranpk/DNFuB/4/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Imran, I originally have the datepicker working, I used the Jquuery calendar. Im trying to get the calendar to allow me to select more than one date which seems to be the problem, Your demo only allows the user to select one date?? please advise

Comment: You need to change the code according to this it you can select multiple dates.  check the demo.  http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html

Comment: Hi Imran, got it going with the code posted below,
Then added in the code in the link you provided, This allows me to select as many dates as I want, but I can't un select a date....do you know why this is, or perhaps could provide info on how to resolve this?

Comment: Also, now I am faced with a new problem, the property for my calendar is DateTime, which although allows me to select as many days as I want on the calendar it only saves the last date to the text box ad updates this.Can you possibly provide info on how the text box will update with all the dates selected?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, i got it going
had to...add the following to my layout page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/date.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="@Url.Content("http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/styles/datePicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/styles/demo.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

---

then in my .cshtml file I added (below) after the editor for ref.

```
<script>
            $("#HolidayDate").addClass('date-pick');
            $('.date-pick').datePicker();
</script>
```